# Mac detecting Exposé

Tags: objective-c, macos

This is hard to search for since `Exposé` without an accent is `expose`, a completely unrelated english word, but...

Is it possible to detect when a user goes into Exposé mode on a mac and when they return? If so, how?

I'm writing an accessibility app and Exposé changes all the positions of my windows which causes trouble. I want to "turn off" my app during exposé.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems a little like an XY problem question. Just for the sake of completeness, could you try adding a brief description of what your app does that makes windows moving around a problem? Could be there's a way to accomplish that goal in a way that doesn't depend on absolute positions of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not fully addressing your requirements, it might be sufficient to exclude your app via:

```
[[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary];
```

As per the [NSWindow Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the behaviour should then be:

> The window is unaffected by Exposé; it stays visible and stationary,
>   like the desktop window.

Comment: I'm not sure this would at all address the OP's requirements. If I'm reading between the lines right, an "accessibility" app implies that it's mostly based on looking at the other windows. So it might be the movement of *every other* window that's the problem.

Comment: @millimoose Must confess I wasn't sure myself (hence the language I used in the first sentence), but it might at least be a potential route to follow up.